# Display notifications to everyone viewing a site

Tags: html, notifications

What language do I need to learn to be able to update a page and have everyone viewing it know? For example if I have a form that updates the page with ajax it automatically updates for that user. What I want is a number or something in the corner that lets everyone else know something has been done if they are viewing the page. I am not sure how to do this and was wondering if anyone had any experience with doing this. Not sure what to really call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how "instant" you need it to be. If you want a simple solution, you can just send an AJAX request every so often (maybe every minute or more frequently).

If you want it to be instantaneous, you can use Comet or WebSockets, which work in real-time.

Comment: I will look into comet and websockets. I would like it to be instantaneous